# Custom Django Inline Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

Let's say I have these two models:

```
class Egg(models.Model):
    # some fields

class Spam(models.Model):
    egg = models.ForeignKey(Egg)
    img = models.ImageField()
```

I planned to have the spams inlined to egg  in admin site. The problem is I also want a very customized method on uploading the spam images ([like this](http://garmoncheg.blogspot.com/2011/07/django-creating-multi-upload-form.html)), like having my own view and template. So far, I just got :

```
class CustomInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Spam
    template = 'admin/app/inline.html' # empty

class EggAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [CustomInline, ]
```

The idea is having some kind of gallery of spams and custom image upload in egg admin. (Is this achievable?)

So the questions are:

1. I want to injects variables to be available on the template (spam objects on `inline.html` for gallery) . Is there a way to do this?
2. Is it okay to POST something to a view (upload process)? Or that particular view must be registered first on admin site or something?

I've looked on InlineAdmin source but still have no idea what to do/override

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

using the `form` property you can subclass your `ModelForm` and completely change the way your inline form works.

Comment: definitely, this is the way to go.